# laravel maatwebsite-excel change sheet direction

Tags: laravel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

how can I change sheet direction in laravel maatwebsite excel package?
I want to change from left to right.

```
A B C D
```

to:

```
D C B A
```

this is my code :

```
   $row =  $this->userRepository->getById(1);

        $data = $row;
        Excel::create('test', function ($excel) use($data) {

            $excel->sheet('sheet', function ($sheet) use($data) {
                $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                });

            });
        })->store('xlsx', storage_path('excel/exports'))->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: share your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: @kunal ok I add that to question

Comment: here is the full documentation of maatwebsite http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export

Comment: @kunal yes, I know. but I can't find any option for direction.

Comment: ok @hamid but why you want that type of functionality you just simply create your own headers that are used in sql table

Comment: I don't want to use any other  thing. only I want to know is there a function for this or not?

Comment: no i think there not any functionprovide by maatwebsite excel to change the direction but you can change the oreintation of excel sheet in vertical or horizontal

Answer (score 7):

```
class TractsExport implements FromCollection,WithEvents
{

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [

            BeforeSheet::class  =>function(BeforeSheet $event){
                $event->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true);
            }
        ];
    }
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        retutn Tract::all();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: doc: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#rtl-right-to-left-sheets

Answer (score 2):

you can use simply a `foreach` in your row and use `array_reverse($row)` before submitting to excel

Answer (score 1):

as laravel-Excel is made based on phpExcel then you can use native phpExcel method to the `$excel` object or the `$sheet` object

here is the code to change the sheet direction

```
 $excel->sheet('sheet', function ($sheet) use($data) {
                $sheet->->setRightToLeft(true);
                $sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1', false, false);
                $sheet->row(1, function($row) {
                });
```

Comment: I used your code almost 3 years after you replied, +1 is for that. However, you have used double ->-> in setRightToLeft ... I wanted to edit is but it says: "Suggested edit queue is full". Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

**First Add** :

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\{
  BeforeExport,
  AfterSheet, 
 };
class UploadResult implements  WithStyles, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents { // add here
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->setRightToLeft(true); // this change
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

*To change the Excel sheet direction you can use setRightToLeft(true) as in the below example*

**Link** : [documentation maatwebsite](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html#rtl-right-to-left-sheets)